# load resource from server computer to client computer using java

Tags: java

```
 Resource resource = appContext.getResource("file:D:\\text\\test.txt");
```

In the above line helps to load the resource file from the location **D:\text\test.txt** but i need to load the file from the server the bellow line is shows error how can i do this in another way.

```
Resource resource = appContext.getResource("file:190.158.1.9:D:\\text\\test.txt");
```

Comment: You need to use ftp to copy remotely.